# Everything works in this Ajax submission except for the notice

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

The email still gets sent and delivered, but still no flash message.

form:

```
    <%= form_for :fb_comment, :url => update_reply_feedback_path, :html => { :id => "reply" }, :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :reply, :size => '66x7' %><br>
        <center><%= f.submit "Send Reply"  %></center>
    <% end %>
```

in the layout file:

```
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
   <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<%- end -%>
```

in controller:

```
def reply2_feedback
   ...
   flash.now[:notice] = 'Reply was successfully sent.'
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.js
   end 
end
```

in application.js:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#reply").submit(function() {
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
      return false;
   })
})
```

update_reply.js.erb:

```
$("#flash").html('<div class="notice_alert"><%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>');
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with the way string processing happens inside of single and double quotes? Maybe if you break it into two parts. var htmlstring = "<div class="flash notice"><%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>"  and then set the html with the variable you can debug easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 58 views without a solution i decided to cave to meet the pressure of a deadline and settle for second best by adding a simple alert to the javascript. If anyone does happen upon this question and provides a solution that makes the flash message work, then i'll switch the answer to you. Thanks to those who gave it a shot.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reply").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
        alert("Your reply was emailed.");
        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Reply was successfully sent.'
```

instead.

Comment: You need this since there is no redirect.

Comment: @HakonB and @Dex, thanks for helping. Dex that is very helpful info. Please check console message i added to the question above. I am wondering if my syntax is wrong in the js.erb file.

Comment: Try using FireBug or something similar and check the request and response to figure out what went wrong. You could also check if any javascript errors occur...

Comment: @HakonB, +1 twice for your help. Using firebug i didn't come up with any javascript errors, but in the console it didn't render what i thought it would. See note under "firebug" in original post.

Comment: Could it be that you shouldn't add a variable in the .erb file but instead just add the markup directly in the .html() function?

Comment: @HakonB, i changed it back and the error is exactly the same. Cut the question down but also added more relevant content. See above.